'com.example.test.MyClass' is not a valid destination for tag 'fragment' using nav graph
I'm creating a bottom navigation using fragments and nav graphs in Android Studio (Koala), but when I run the app the navbar is displayed at the top with no fragment displayed and nothing happening on click except a log saying Ignoring onNavDestinationSelected for MenuItem.
Android Studio is warning me on the lines marked below that the classes are not a valid destination for tag 'fragment'. Both the layout and class file for ManageCategories and ManageUsers were working before adding the nav (and haven't been changed since).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/manageCategoriesFragment">

    <!-- Manage Categories Fragment -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/manageCategoriesFragment"
        android:name="com.example.rentanything.ManageCategoriesFragment" // this line
        android:label="Categories"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_manage_categories" />

    <!-- Manage Users Fragment -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/manageUsersFragment"
        android:name="com.example.rentanything.ManageUsersFragment" // this line
        android:label="Users"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_manage_users" />
</navigation>

Here is my activity_admin.xml which is where the nav graph is being referenced:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AdminActivity">

    <!-- NavHostFragment for managing the fragments -->
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/admin_nav_graph"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <!-- Bottom Navigation View -->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_admin"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


what is your package name?

com.example.rentanything. The package name in the post title was changed by accident
